# Is there any verb or phrase for "making something incomplete"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, verbs

For example, a customer asks a jeweler to sell her a set of jewelry except for a ring in the set. But the jeweler says that he can't exclude the ring because it would **make the set incomplete**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*to break up*:

> 9. Destroy the completeness of a set of related items
>      *"The book dealer would not break up the set"*

(source: [WordWeb online](https://www.wordwebonline.com/en/BREAKUP))